# How to update recyclerview items dynamically at specific position from service class?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-recyclerview

I'm having a animation item in recycler view here i'm trying set it's visiblity to visible and invisible from service for that i have successfully created methods and recycler view is getting manipulated but here the main problem is that when i click on first recycler view item say at position 1 i'm setting visibility of my animation view to visible however if i click on another item set no 5 then that item visibility will be set properly however i want to make the previous clicked item to be invisible how can i do that?

here is my code when i'm setting visiblity inside on click:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                   holder.playanim.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        })
```

this is my xml item:

```
 <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/playinganim"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_fileName="playing.json"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sname"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some extra logic. Use a variable to store the last clicked position and check whether the current item position equals last checked position.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.yourView.setVisibility(position == lastCheckedPosition ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notifyItemChanged(lastCheckedPosition);
                lastCheckedPosition = position;
            }
        });
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }
```